# Замена boost::asio::socket на boost::asio::serial_port

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Имеется класс который по проприетарному протоколу шлет на сервер сообщения по IP/TCP.
Дело в том что на новом устройстве сервер находится там же где и клиент(на одной и той-же машине) и общение с ним происходит через serial port.
В моем классе используются бустовские функции async_read, async_write и они принимают и объекты класса boost:;asio::ip::tcp::socket, и boost::asio::serial_port.
То есть для того чтобы использовать серийный порт надо просто тип у переменной сменить и все будет ОК, но дело в том что хочется чтобы класс универсальным и чтобы он поддерживал и то и то.
Вопрос: есть ли какой нить общий родитель или супер класс от которого наследованы концепции async_read и async_write чтобы можно было бы быстро и удобно менять сокет на серийник?

Comment: Это шаблонные функции, поэтому они принимают и то и другое, т.к. это https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncWriteStream.html

Comment: Да, но в коде вызывается функция async_connect для сокета которая не пашет с serial_port. очень интересно как создать такой тип, чтобы он мог быть по нажатию 1 клавиши серийником или сокетом.